# Why the content of id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files are letters?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am trying to implement `RSA` algorithm and as per the algorithm public key and private keys are based on the very large numbers and the resulting, `private` key and `public key` are also a number.

For instance to generate the private key and public key

let's choose

```
p = 7
q = 19

n = p * q = 133
m = (p-1) * (q-1) = 108

e = 5 
d = (1 + i * m) /e
   for i = 0, 1, 2 .. n 
d = 65
```

Here we get 
Public key pair (n, e) = `(133, 5)`
Private key pair (n, d) = `(133,65)`

Encryption: `p^e%n`
Decryption: `c^d%n`

But. As I know the `public key` and `private key` generate by `ssh-keygen` command is `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

While inspecting the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` I found the letters instead of a very large number.

How theses `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` are used to encrypt the data.

Comment: There are two things you need to understand about these key formats. The first is relatively easy: binary data is base64-encoded. That's what those letters and numbers are. Therefore you must base64-decode them to get the bytes and begin to make sense out of it. The second and harder thing is how the various components are laid out in the byte sequence. Different standards exist for different systems. Search for information on the format of ssh private and public keys.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Better post that as an answer, we won't be able to do much more with the question other than pointing out the info that you pointed out above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, those files are encoded in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format. But if you ask, **what** is encoded in base64, that is where things start to go in the weeds. The primary motive of files is to store some numbers that are used in the RSA calculations. They are not meant for humans to be read since it's not space friendly. They are meant for machine to process, and fast, so it has to be written in a format that machines can easily load and start using.

If you look at a standard called [JWK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) or **JSON Web Key**, you will see how the keys are passed around among applications. eg:
A private key

```
{
    "kty": "EC",
    "d": "u5uui9SeGmkorTrbXtOGWAaov1cLCZXt3kleSxzH8T0",
    "use": "sig",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "a3JvmNVFxue8gyAdtH_Pca87CKjh82j7mMRzHhS3_IA",
    "y": "JdEC03zi2IatFVjrp1o4ear32gBe4E0xiFf_EDt8unM",
    "alg": "ES256"
}
```

and a public key:

```
{
    "kty": "EC",
    "use": "sig",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "a3JvmNVFxue8gyAdtH_Pca87CKjh82j7mMRzHhS3_IA",
    "y": "JdEC03zi2IatFVjrp1o4ear32gBe4E0xiFf_EDt8unM",
    "alg": "ES256"
}
```

These might a more human readable form, but if you observe, they are in a serialized string format. They will have to go from string to JSON to field extraction and then convert them to objects which can then be used.

The files that are generated by openssl and openssh are more in the format closer to what machines like. I would recommend to use openssl to play around with openssh since they are much more wide spread. There is a spec, **`x509`**, which the world uses for cryptography to share keys around. Openssh is built on a bit different spec and they keys generated are written in a different format.

If you want to see the big numbers, there are 2 ways:

But first, lets generate a key to play around with. We will generate a 512-bit key just to keep it small.

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 512
```

1. Easy way, ask a tool to help: Given that you have the above file with you, you can ask openssl to parse it dump the info for you.

```
$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -noout -text
RSA Private-Key: (512 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:a9:...
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:8c:...
prime1:
    00:da:...
prime2:
    00:c6:...
exponent1:
    4e:0d:...
exponent2:
    76:66:...
coefficient:
    00:92:...
```

The numbers are ellipsis-ed just to keep it small.
Another way to look at this is:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -in key.pem -inform PEM
```

You will see the output with the huge numbers that you are expecting.

2. The hard way: These numbers are packed in format called **`ASN1`**. If you read the binary in the format as encoded, you will be able to see the numbers in the binaries too.

But first, need to convert the openssh keys into the required format, called the PEM format.

```
ssh-keygen -f id_rsa.pub -e -m pem > pubkey.pem
```

Now, we can do a `openssl asn1parse -in pubkey.pem -inform PEM` and see the details.

```
$ ssh-keygen -f id_rsa.pub -e -m pem | openssl asn1parse -inform PEM
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

Please read this answer to understand how these numbers are encoded into the PEM format:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59235177/6266958

Comment: Have you even checked the ssh files in question to see if this answer is relevant? For example, asn1parse only makes sense if the data is the encoding of ASN.1 object.

Comment: Yes, which is why I have mentioned the following text "But first, need to convert the openssh keys into the required format, called the PEM format". The whole answer was to direct towards using openssl instead of using openssh since openssl generates keys in a more wider format.

Comment: My bad sir, I missed that line.